# Should predictions with negative binomial regression only produce integers?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution

I have a dataset consisting of about 600 observations. Each observation has around 100 attributes. One of the attributes I want to predict. Since the attribute that I want to predict can only have non-negative integer values, I was looking for ways to predict count data and found that there are various options, such as Poisson regression or negative binomial regression.

For my first try I used negative binomial regression in `R`:

```
#First load the data into a dataset
dataset <- test_observations[, c(5:8, 54)]

#Create the model
fm_nbin <- glm.nb(NumberOfIncidents ~ ., data = dataset[10:600, ] )
```

I then wanted to see how to predicted values look like:

```
#Create data to test prediction
newdata <- dataset[1:10, ]

#Do the prediction
predict(fm_nbin, newdata, type="response")
```

Now the problem is the output looks like this:

```
     1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
0.2247337 0.2642789 0.2205408 0.2161833 0.1794224 0.2081522 0.2412996 0.2074992 0.2213011 0.2100026
```

The problem with this is that I expected that the predicted values are integers, since that is the whole purpose of using a negative binomial regression. What am I missing here?

Furthermore, I would like to evaluate my predictions in terms of mean squared error and mean absolute error, as well as a correlation coefficient. However, I couldn't find a way to get these easily, without doing all the calculations manually. Is there any built-in function for this?

Comment: Welcome to our site! Have you looked at the [many related questions on interpreting negative binomial regression output](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interpret+negative+binomial)?

Comment: Yes I did, but I think those questions are about how to interpret AIC, BIC, or the different coefficients. What I want to now, if I would use this model to actually predict my data, why is the output a floating point number and not an integer?

Comment: I find specific answers at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48448, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116007, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60777, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25440. Most explanations of logistic regression and GLMs generally will also apply, too. Your post actually asks an awful lot of questions implicitly, because it is based on several misconceptions--and these explanations address some of them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that glm's model E[y|X]. Therefore, the predict function for glm.nb is giving you E[y|X]. The standard example of a non-integer expected value is rolling a die. You can only get integers as outcomes. However, the expected value (3.5) is not an integer.

As for the mean squared error, checkout Hans Roggeman's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83990/deviance-in-generalized-linear-models-for-different-families). It helped me understand model comparison better.